# preg_match returns only one (last) result

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to parse this string with `preg_match` function to get name of array and all indexes:

> {#array[index1][index2][index3] ... }

I tried this regex, but in `$matches` is only the last index (`[index3]`):

```
$string = "{#array[index1][index2][index3]}";
preg_match('|^\{\#[a-z0-9_\-]+(\[[a-z0-9_-]+\])*\}|i',$string,$matches);
```

results:

```
Array
(
    [0] => {#array[index1][index2][index3]}
    [1] => [index3]
)
```

Can somone help me, please?

BTW: `preg_match_all` returns the same result

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Oh sorry, i want to get name of array and all indexes, forex. array("index1","index2","index3")

Comment: Great place to test: [regex101.com](https://www.regex101.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `\G` anchor in-order to do a continuous string match.

```
(?:\{#([a-z0-9_\-]+)|(?<!^)\G)\[([^\[\]]+)\](?=[^{}]*\})
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xM0hA6/5)

Answer (score 1):

Preg_match does indeed only match one.

If you want to match more data with your regex, you'll need [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php).

Comment: It's the same result when i use preg_match_all.